# Why does an updated, modified DB file still contain old, previous schemas?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, migration

Foremost, I'm an Android developer and SQLite noob -- I've only done a few very simple apps as well as worked with SQL, MySQL, and related DBMSs but not SQLite before.

I'm trying to implement a database, decided to utilize Room with a pre-populated DB file -- using DB Browser for SQLite to create, update the file. One of the problems is I receive errors complaining the schemas don't match ("expected", "found"). Initially, I had mistakenly chosen data types not compatible with Room. I changed them, some even accidentally -- darn auto-selected drop-down menus -- but ultimately fixed them all.

Here's the comparison...

```
Expected:
TableInfo{name='Ingredient', columns={unit_system=Column{name='unit_system', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, amount=Column{name='amount', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, recipe_id=Column{name='recipe_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ingredient_id=Column{name='ingredient_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, unit_size=Column{name='unit_size', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, prep_type=Column{name='prep_type', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, food_id=Column{name='food_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Food', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[food_id], referenceColumnNames=[id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Recipe', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[recipe_id], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[]}
Found:
TableInfo{name='Ingredient', columns={unit_system=Column{name='unit_system', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, amount=Column{name='amount', type='NUMERIC', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, recipe_id=Column{name='recipe_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ingredient_id=Column{name='ingredient_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, unit_size=Column{name='unit_size', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, prep_type=Column{name='prep_type', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, food_id=Column{name='food_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

I've tried:

- deleting the file from the project, restarting Android Studio, then pasting the newer one
- editing it as a text file in Android Studio
- deleting the file from the project, Invalidate Caches / Restart, then paste the newer one
- deleting the file, recreate the database from scratch, add it back to the project assets

Here are the CREATE statements from DB Browser:

```
CREATE TABLE "Food" (
"id"    INTEGER,
"name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT))

CREATE TABLE "Ingredient" (
"ingredient_id" INTEGER,
"amount"    REAL NOT NULL,
"unit_size" TEXT,
"prep_type" TEXT,
"food_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
"recipe_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"unit_system"   TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("ingredient_id" AUTOINCREMENT))

CREATE TABLE "Recipe" (
"id"    INTEGER,
"name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
"category"  TEXT NOT NULL,
"media" TEXT NOT NULL,
"servings_amt"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"servings_type" TEXT NOT NULL,
"directions_us" TEXT NOT NULL,
"directions_metric" TEXT NOT NULL,
"tags"  TEXT,
"favorite"  INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT))
```

Here's what appears in Android Studio (auto opens after pasted)

> SQLite format 3   @                                                                     .G�
> � �9
> ��                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   �!!�tableIngredientIngredientCREATE TABLE "Ingredient" (
> "ingredient_id" INTEGER,
> "amount"    REAL NOT NULL,
> "unit_size" TEXT,
> "prep_type" TEXT,
> "food_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
> "recipe_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
> "unit_system"   TEXT NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY("ingredient_id" AUTOINCREMENT)
> )�_�tableRecipeRecipeCREATE TABLE "Recipe" (
> "id"    INTEGER,
> "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
> "category"  TEXT NOT NULL,
> "media" TEXT NOT NULL,
> "severings_amt" INTEGER NOT NULL,
> "servings_type" TEXT NOT NULL,
> "directions_us" TEXT NOT NULL,
> "directions_metric" TEXT NOT NULL,
> "tags"  TEXT,
> "favorite"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
> )P++Ytablesqlite_sequencesqlite_sequenceCREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)s�ItableFoodFoodCREATE TABLE "Food" (
> "id"    INTEGER,
> "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
> )

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you fix the data types. Did you delete and recreate the tables with the correct data types?

Comment: No, I used DB Browser's modify feature. However, at this point, it might be best just to recreate the database file from scratch.

Comment: SQLite does not support modifying the data type of a column. Read this: https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far. However, it appears, the mystery is still unsolved. I've updated my original post which includes that I now recreated the DB file from scratch, and now the resulting file shown in Android Studio has no mention of temp tables or duplicate tables with different schemas. Basically, the file now looks good from all sources except one, Room still seems to see the "Amount" column in the "Ingredient" table as a NUMERIC type not a REAL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm seeing this correctly or not, but...
Your Create SQL is

```
    CREATE TABLE "Ingredient" (
"ingredient_id" INTEGER,
"amount"    REAL NOT NULL,
"unit_size" TEXT,
"prep_type" TEXT,
"food_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
"recipe_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"unit_system"   TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("ingredient_id" AUTOINCREMENT))
```

Shouldn't it be

```
CREATE TABLE "Ingredient" (
"ingredient_id" INTEGER,
"amount"    NUMERIC NOT NULL,
"unit_size" TEXT,
"prep_type" TEXT,
"food_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
"recipe_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"unit_system"   TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("ingredient_id" AUTOINCREMENT))
```